# Prevent Visual Studio web project start https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express

i have a web project where i wanted to start with SSL then in HTTPS, so doing some configurations... now i changed idea and i want to start without HTTPS, i cleaned my configurations, but when i run the project, IIS Express starts 2 projects, (see images). What can i do to remove the project with https?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your Solution properties to specify which projects should start?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there are a few things to check

1. make sure you Clean and Rebuild,
2. delete all Temp files from Windows\Microsoft.Net\Frameworks then 64 or 32 bit.
3. Have you created the actual app in IIS by hitting the "Create Virtual Directory button"? 
   If you have, then https will be a binding there, so just go and delete that.
4. Finally check your web.config, to make sure there is no https reference sticking around anywhere.

One of these should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually open .vs/config/applicationHost.config (VS2015) to remove the https binding from that site, or Documents\IIS Express\config\applicationHost.config (VS2013 or below). Of course, you can use Jexus Manager for IIS Express to do the same using a simple user interface, http://jexusmanager.com